# Render different component based on device type (best practice)?

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface

I have a button for a UI i'm building.

```
<button
      onMouseEnter={handleModalOpen}
      onMouseLeave={handleModalClose}
      className="info-button"
    >
      info
    </button>
```

when you mouse over the button it opens a modal at the cursor position with some info.
On mobile it works with a tap. Here's the code i'm using to get the cursor position:

```
  useEffect(() => {
const update = (e) => {
  setX(e.x);
  setY(e.y);
};
window.addEventListener("mousemove", update);
window.addEventListener("touchmove", update);
return () => {
  window.removeEventListener("mousemove", update);
  window.removeEventListener("touchmove", update);
};
}, [setX, setY]);
```

I want to also have the option to click the button to open a new page with more info, however this creates an issue on mobile as the click to navigate and mouseover (or tap in this case) are conflicting.

I'm wondering if there's a way to render a similar component for mobile? so that I can move the onClick function to the modal instead of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those still interested I found a solution.

this package:
[react device detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect)

it provides a bunch of conditions which check for loads of different browsers, OSes and devices:

just import the selectors you need:

```
import { isBrowser, isMobile } from 'react-device-detect';
```

and use like any other conditional:

```
 if (isMobile) {
  // do something
}
```